# How to optimize the code and reduce memory usage Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

The purpose is to reduce **memory usage**.
Meaning that it should be optimized in a way that the `hash` is equal to the `test hash`.

What I've tried so far:

1. Adding `__slots__` but it didn't make any changes.
2. Change default *dtype* `float64` to `float32`. Although it reduces the mem usage significantly, it brakes the test by changing the hash.
3. Converted data into `np.array` reduced CPU times: *`from 13 s to 2.05 s`* but didn't affect the **memory usage**.

The code to reproduce:

```
rows = 40000000
trs = 10

random.seed(42)

generated_data: tp.List[float] = np.array([random.random() for _ in range(rows)])



def df_upd(df_initial: pd.DataFrame, df_new: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return pd.concat((df_initial, df_new), axis=1)


class T:
    """adding a column of random data"""
    __slots__ = ['var']
    def __init__(self, var: float):
        self.var = var

    def transform(self, df_initial: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
        return df_upd(df_initial, pd.DataFrame({self.var: generated_data}))


class Pipeline:
    __slots__ = ['df', 'transforms']
    def __init__(self):
        self.df = pd.DataFrame()
        self.transforms = np.array([T(f"v{i}") for i in range(trs)])

    def run(self):
        for t in self.transforms:
            self.df = t.transform(self.df)
        return self.df


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    
    # starting the monitoring
    tracemalloc.start()

    # function call
    pipe = Pipeline()
    %time df = pipe.run()
    print("running")

    # displaying the memory
    current, peak = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()
    print(f"Current memory usage is {current / 10**3} KB ({(current / 10**3)*0.001} MB); Peak was {peak / 10**3} KB ({(peak / 10**3)*0.001} MB); Diff = {(peak - current) / 10**3} KB ({((peak - current) / 10**3)*0.001} MB)")

    # stopping the library
    tracemalloc.stop()
    
    # should stay unchanged
    %time hashed_df = hashlib.sha256(pd.util.hash_pandas_object(df, index=True).values).hexdigest()
    print("hashed_df", hashed_df)    
    
    assert hashed_df == test_hash

    print("Success!")
```

Comment: It seems to me this question is more suited to be asked in the  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Comment: At a first glance it looks like your code would not pass type checking. E.g. `generated_data: tp.List[float]` should probably be closer to `generated_data: np.ndarray`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you avoid `pd.concat()` and use the *preferred* way of augmenting dataframes:

```
df["new_col_name"] = new_col_data
```

this will reduce peak memory consumption significantly.

---

In your code it is sufficient to fix the `Transform` class:

```
class Transform:
    """adding a column of random data"""
    __slots__ = ['var']
    def __init__(self, var: str):
        self.var = var

    def transform(self, df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
        df[self.var] = generated_data
        return df
```

(Note that I also changed the `type` of `var` from `float` to `str` to reflect how it is used in the code).

---

In my machine I went from:

> Current memory usage is 1600110.987 KB (1600.110987 MB); Peak was 4480116.325 KB (4480.116325 MB); Diff = 2880005.338 KB (2880.005338 MB)

to:

> Current memory usage is 1760101.105 KB (1760.101105 MB); Peak was 1760103.477 KB (1760.1034769999999 MB); Diff = 2.372 KB (0.002372 MB)

(I am not sure why the current memory usage is slightly higher in this case).

---

For faster computation, you may want to do some pre-allocation.

To do that, you could replace, in Pipeline's `__init__()`:

```
self.df = pd.DataFrame()
```

with:

```
self.df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.empty((rows, trs)), columns=[f"v{i}" for i in range(trs)])
```

---

If you want to get even faster, you can compute the DataFrame right away in the Pipeline's `__init__`, e.g.:

```
class Pipeline:
    __slots__ = ['df', 'transforms']
    def __init__(self):
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(data=generated_data[:, None] + np.zeros(trs)[None, :], columns=[f"v{i}" for i in range(trs)])

    def run(self):
        return self.df
```

but I assume your `Transform` is a proxy of a more complex operation and I am not sure this simplification is easy to adapt beyond the toy code in the question.

Comment: Thanks it is really helped to reduce memory, but somehow it affected cpu times. It increased from 2 sec to 11 sec. Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: @Vagner I updated the answer to address performances. Essentially you can either do some pre-allocation, or, even faster, create the DataFrame right away. Hope it helps!